# CodeMirror XML Mode: Read all attributes

Tags: xml, codemirror

is there a way in CodeMirror running in XML mode to read all attributes of a tag at cursor position?

The token at the cursor can be determined via

`var cur = cm.getCursor(),
    token = cm.getTokenAt(cur);`

Example:
The statement "`<mytag id="1" name="Test"/>`" could result in this:

`{
  id: "1",
  name: "Test"
}`

Thanks for any advices.

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone!

```
cm.on("cursorActivity", function () {
    var cur = cm.getCursor(),
        tagList = [
            "control",
            "fql",
            "text"
        ],
        range = cm.getViewport(),
        attributes = {};

    range.from = Math.min(range.from, cur.line);
    range.to = Math.max(cur.line + 1, range.to);

    var match = CodeMirror.findMatchingTag(cm, cur, range);

    if (match && match.at === "open" && tagList.indexOf(match.open.tag.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
        var doc = cm.getDoc(),
            tagLine = doc.getRange(match.open.from, match.open.to, false).join(""),
            re = /(\S+)\s*?=\s*(['"])(.*?|)\2/g,
            m;

        while ((m = re.exec(tagLine)) !== null) {
            if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
                re.lastIndex++;
            }

            attributes[m[1]] = m[3];
        }

        console.log(attributes);
    }
});
```